# after list add some object and set object null

Tags: java

```
class TestEntity {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public TestEntity(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", x -> " + x + ", y -> " + y;
    }
}

TestEntity t = new TestEntity(666, 777);
List<TestEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(t);
t = null;
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

why correct print `list.get(0)` with

> @xxxxx,x -> 666, y -> 777

if I remove `t = null;` and do `t.x = 888`, the print looks correct.

Comment: can you be a bit more clear in your question?

Comment: `t = null;` just dereference the variable `t`, but doesn't change anything on the `TestEntity` object that it referenced previously. You should learn/search about "java references"

Comment: Can you define the result you hae, and what you expected?

Comment: you cahnge the reference of t when yyou do t=null, that doesnt mean the TestEntity in the list is modified thoe

Comment: Java is pass-by-value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value. This is a duplicate

Comment: What logical should be applied here to think that `t=null` would affect the object added to the list? You __obviously__ don't add `t` to the list, but rather the reference to an object currently hold by `t`. If you alter `t` to refer to something else (a new object or `null`) then it obviously doesn't matter much to `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `t` in  `list`, `t` and the first element of `list` refer to the same object.

But as you write `t = null`, it assigns `null` to the `t` variable.
So, now `t` and the first element of `list` doesn't refer any longer to the same object.
So printing the first or the second will give distinct result.

As you write `t.x = 888`, `t` and the first element of `list` refer still to the same object.
You change only the value of a field of the object.
So printing the first one or the second give exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting an object to null. You're setting a **reference** to an object to null.

`t` is a reference to an object. When calling `list.add(t)`, you're storing a **copy** of this reference (let's call it `t2`) inside the list. So you end up with

```
t -----> theObject
           ^
           |           
ArrayList [t2]
```

Two references both pointing at the same object.

Now, when you execute `t = null`, you just change what `t` points to. The copy, stored in the list, doesn't care about that. Only `t` now points to no object at all (null). So you end up with

```
t--> nothing    theObject
                   ^
                   |           
        ArrayList [t2]
```

So, printing the first element of the list still prints the object that is referenced by `t2`, the first reference in the list internal array.